# Linked list from different class nodes

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list for an assignment that kind of simulates the basket of a grocery market in which the basket is the linked list and node(link) in it is each product. The below code represents the basket (LinkedList) and some products Gouda and Bacon. My question is how can I make a linked list out of those two nodes so I can get a LinkedList like Gouda->Bacon->Bacon->Gouda etc ?

p.s Thank you in  advance

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList theLinkedList = new LinkedList();
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink();
    theLinkedList.display();
   }
}

class LinkedList{

// Reference to first Link in list
// The last Link added to the LinkedList

public Gouda firstLink; 

LinkedList(){

    // Here to show the first Link always starts as null

    firstLink = null;

}

// Returns true if LinkList is empty

public boolean isEmpty(){

    return(firstLink == null);

}

public void insertFirstLink(){

    Gouda newLink = new Gouda();

    // Connects the firstLink field to the new Link 

    newLink.next = firstLink;

    firstLink = newLink;

}


public void display(){

    Gouda theLink = firstLink;

    // Start at the reference stored in firstLink and
    // keep getting the references stored in next for
    // every Link until next returns null

    while(theLink != null){

        theLink.display();

        System.out.println("Next Link: " + theLink.next);

        theLink = theLink.next;

        System.out.println();

    }

    }
}

public class Gouda{

// Set to public so getters & setters aren't needed

    public String category= "Dairy";
    public String productName = "Gouda Cheese";
    public double price = 57.50;

    // Reference to next link made in the LinkList
    // Holds the reference to the Link that was created before it
    // Set to null until it is connected to other links

    public Gouda next; 

    public void display(){

        System.out.println(category+" :"+ productName +""+ price);

    }   
}

public class Bacon{

// Set to public so getters & setters aren't needed

    public String category= "Meat";
    public String productName = "Thick cut Bacon";
    public double price = 5.50;

    // Reference to next link made in the LinkList
    // Holds the reference to the Link that was created before it
    // Set to null until it is connected to other links

    public Bacon next; 

    public void display(){

        System.out.println(category+" :"+ productName +""+ price);

    }   
}
```

Comment: In java that is solved by having every link of the list being a container like class, Node, that has a value field, for instance Object (Gouda and Bacon are Objects), and so on.

Comment: Your own implementation of LinkedList? Why don't you like the default Java's LinkedList? Regarding your questions - consider making both Gouda and Bacon the subclassed of a basic Product class (class Bacon extends Product). After that just use List<Product> products = new LinkedList<Product>();

But, if you need your own implementation due to different reasons, you can still create an interface called Product. And both you classes should implement this interface, so in result you will be able to write `Product gouda = new Gouda();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a new class, for instance `Product`, with `Gouda` and `Bacon` defined as subclasses of it.

Then in the linked list you define firstLink as:

```
public Product firstLink;
```

and always use Product inside the class `LinkedList`. In this way you can insert both instances of `Goude` and `Bacon` in a list, since they are `Product`.

This is the basic idea of subclass and inheritance.

Comment: Ok so I created a new class called Product with an empty display() and a public Product next to assign the next Link but when I declare a new  link Gouda newLink = new Gouda() I get an error in the  newLink.next = firstLink saying it cannot convert it to Product to Gouda. Since Gouda is a subclass of Product why is that happening?

Comment: You should do Product newLink = new Gouda.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and by changing that it got solved... I know the problem got solved and all but can you explain why Gouda newLink = new Gouda() didn't work and Product newLink = new Gouda() worked?

Comment: This is because you were redefining newLink with a type subtype of Product, and this operation is not permitted by the type system of Java. Google about "covariance vs. controvariance" to see why.